# How to handle Currency in Java 8?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8

What is the preferred way to handle currencies in `Java 8`?

The things that could be of interest would be

```
* Currency Full Name (e.g. United States Dollar)  
* Currency Abbreviation (e.g. USD)  
* Currency Symbol (e.g. $)
```

Any other thing that I might be missing here?

What are the best options?

Comment: Well, there's [joda-money](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-money), among others. But why would currency handling be any different in Java 8, than any other version? Also, if you're asking for recommended libraries and such, you probably know this is off topic for SO.

Comment: On a related note, Java 9 will introduce a set of Money classes and methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java 8 still uses [`java.util.Currency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) and ISO 4217 codes. From the Javadoc,

> Represents a currency. Currencies are identified by their ISO 4217 currency codes. Visit the [ISO web site](http://www.iso.org/iso/en/prods-services/popstds/currencycodes.html) for more information, including a table of currency codes.
>
> The class is designed so that there's never more than one `Currency` instance for any given currency. Therefore, there's no public constructor. You obtain a `Currency` instance using the `getInstance` methods.
>
> Users can supersede the Java runtime currency data by means of the system property `java.util.currency.data.`